# Possible Chrome 45 bug: removeChild method causes other nodes in parent element to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I`ve faced an issue with Chrome version 45.

**Issue:**
When i do try to remove last child div with JavaScript the Chrome engine hides all other tags in parent div (span and b tags will be hidden):

```
<div class='parentDiv' id='pdiv'>
    Some text <span style='color:red;'>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</span> more example text more example <b style="color:green;">more</b> example text more example more example text more example more example text more example more example text example text example text example text example text example text example text example text example text example text
    <div id='secondChild' style='color:blue;'>
        This div should be removed.
    </div>
</div>
<span class='Execute' onclick="removChild()"><b>Click me</b></span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var removChild = function() {
        document.getElementById('pdiv').removeChild(document.getElementById('secondChild'))
    }
</script>
```

It looks as though only the current Chrome version(45) is affected. Beta and dev channels are not affected. For testing I`ve used clean Chrome version (without extensions). Also, I didn't find this issue in the Chromium issue report list.

**Note**: Lools like this is only happening if parent div content is bigger than 250 characters.

**Question**: Is there something wrong with my html structure or is it definitely a Chrome issue?

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1L92tLsu/)**

**Examples**:
[Example link 1: content of parent div - 448 symbols](http://goo.gl/nMWFTj) 
[Example link 2: content of parent div - 197 symbols](http://goo.gl/lV1sgF)

Comment: that's bizarre - the red text just goes transparent until you select it, or resize that frame ... you can make the green text do the same by a simple change to the HTML - see http://jsfiddle.net/1L92tLsu/1/

Comment: "Lools like this is only happening if parent div content is bigger than 250 characters." - not, actually, it seems that it happens because of <b> tag (tried with <strong> tag - got same, undesired result)... Very strange, indeed... Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1L92tLsu/2/ If you remove <strong> tags all is fine... :)

Comment: Yes, also  it can be easy solved by adding dummy div tag after first div child (http://jsfiddle.net/p24bLyfe/) or just changing tag name div->span , though  sadly my project was affected and that was hard to catch as before recent Chrome update everything worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of chrome is 46.0.2490.71, and your code works fine for me. This does look like a chrome bug to me. you can use `lastElementChild` to remove secondChild, but it has to be the last child inside of parentDiv that you are removing.

you can replace your script with this one:

```
var removChild = function() {
    var lastChild = document.getElementById('pdiv');
    lastChild.removeChild(lastChild.lastElementChild);
}
```

Here is a link to test this code for your version of Chrome: http://mashpoe.comeze.com/test.html